# missing data for column xxx

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis, osm2pgsql

I've downloaded multiple metro extracts from openstreetmap as PBF files when i try to import them with osm2pgsql it works for the first and creates the tables. I then want to add a column in the planet_osm_ways with a cityID to know which "way id" belonged to which city after i then try to import another city it says 'ERROR: Missing data for column "city_id". is there a way to modify the planet_osm_ways table without breaking the script? I really need to know which id belonged to which metro extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  need to edit the style file (`default.style`, possibly in osm2pgsql-bin directory) used by osm2pgsql. 
You can then add the instruction

```
#Add custom column
node,way   citiid      int4         linear
```

The column will be created, and - provided no tag has this name - will not be populated. You are then free to populate it as you want.

Comment: This works great on all the tables expect for the planet_osm_ways table is there a way to get that in there? i use the -s command to generate roads,rels and ways tables. On the roads table it created the column but on the ways it didn't. Is there a way to say on which specific table you want the column generated?